# Password and Login verse very long string (token)

Tags: authentication, passwords, oauth, user-names

I'm building a PHP login system that uses a username and password at first to grant the user a token and uses that token to grant the user access to their account.

My original thought was to force the access_token to refresh often, closing the window for potential brute force attacks.

However, after thinking it over, I realize that the access_token may be more secure than a username and password...

If I have a username of 24 characters, and a password of 24 characters, won't a 128 character access_token still be more secure? Let's assume all are using alphanumeric characters.

#### Edit

It seems that the above statement was a bit veg. I'll be a bit more specific.

**Scenarios**

*Example A*

I have one system with a 24 character alphanumeric username and a 24 character alphanumerics password.

*Example B*

I have another system with a 128 character alphanumeric token.

**Question**

If two computers set out to brute force both systems, which system would most likely take the longest?

Comment: Does the token change everytime a user enters their credentials?

Comment: Yes - But that is beside the point. Even if it didn't, wouldn't it be more secure than a username and password?

Comment: Apart from character size, the security would also depend on architecture. If you had a strong token but if an attacker can see it once and use it the next time, its as secure as the password

Comment: Of course Limit, there are a lot of things that need to be considered. Right now I'm focusing on this aspect of the project.

Comment: Fair but a lot of people just rely on the character size so wanted to ensure that you had covered the bases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to judge purely based on character size and wanted to compare a 24 character username and 24 character password system vs a 128 character token system, I would say that the search space would be larger in the token based system.

Obviously, to brute-force a username/password combination, the user needs to find a pair in two n^24 search spaces while in the there are several elements in the n^128 sized token search space that will be valid tokens. As a result, it can happen that your brute-force system does find a token before it can find a valid username/password pair. But finding all valid username/password pairs will take less time than finding all valid tokens.

Comment: Are you saying it is likely that a brute force attack will find a valid token before a valid username and password? Or are you saying it is possible that a brute force attack will find a valid token before a valid username and password?

Comment: @jacobhenning I am saying that it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are away to provide access to a resource without the need to have a session managed indefinitely. This allows you scale servers and limit overhead pretty effectively by authorizing a client to access a resource directly.

Your Username / Password is used to [Authenticate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) a person. Once you can prove that person is who they say they are, you issue the access token.

[Access Tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_token) are short-lived, and used to access resources directly, or in basic terms [Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization).

There are also [Refresh Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current), which are long-lived, and used to request a new access token after your current one expires.

In terms of security when discussion what you are trying to do, it's not a matter of Username/password vs Token. It's a matter of whether your trying to build a more stateless system (using access tokens) or using a more traditional approach and managing long sessions.

On top of that you really don't need to be rolling your own Token System. [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (JSON Web Tokens) already implement the RFC 7519 standard for token based access which I recommend.

You may get security people that might favor traditional based sessions, but personally Token Based is a lot more pragmatic. OAuth has a nice little break down [here](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/).

Comment: Thanks Shane, everything you said was helpful and made sense, but you didn't really answer my question. Sure, I may not need to build out my own Token System, but I am and so I wanted to know where the biggest security risk is. If the login was less secure, I would rely more on tokens, and Vise Versa.